# Replacing 'NA's in a nested list

Tags: python, nested-loops, nested-lists

I am trying to do the following: identify if there is a 'NA' value in a nested list, and if so, to replace it with the average value of the sum of the other elements of the list. The elements of the lists should be floats. For example:

```
[["1.2","3.1","0.2"],["44.0","NA","90.0"]]
```

should return

```
[[1.2, 3.1, 0.2], [44.0, 67.0, 90.0]]
```

The code below, albeit long and redundant, works:

```
def convert_data(data):
    first = []
    second = []
    third = []
    fourth = []
    count = 0
    for i in data:
        for y in i:
            if 'NA' not in i:
                y = float(y)
                first.append(y)
            elif 'NA' in i:
                a = i.index('NA')
                second.append(y)
    second[a] = 0

    for q in second:
        q = float(q)
        third.append(q)
        count+= q

    length = len(third)
    count = count/(length-1)
    third[a] = count
    fourth.extend([first,third])
    return fourth

data = [["1.2","3.1","0.2"],["44.0","NA","90.0"]]
convert_data(data)
```

for example:

```
data = [["1.2","3.1","0.2"],["44.0","NA","90.0"]] 
convert_data(data)
```

returns the desired output:

```
[[1.2, 3.1, 0.2], [44.0, 67.0, 90.0]]
```

but if the 'NA' is in the first list e.g.

```
data = [["1.2","NA","0.2"],["44.0","67.00","90.0"]]
```

then it doesn't. Can someone please explain how to fix this?

Comment: It is bonkers IMO that some people are suggesting you need to import third-party computing packages to handle a simple computation like this.

Comment: @BenQuigley That depends entirely on the rest of OP's program, however. If they're performing a bunch of operations on what is clearly tabular data, they should use more appropriate tools.

Comment: OP, I think we need a bit more information from you in order to answer this question properly. On top of what I mentioned above regarding the rest of your program and data, for example, do the sublists always contain 3 elements?

Comment: I forgot to add: What happens if the sublist is composed entirely of `'NA'` values? While we're on the topic, using the string `'NA'` like this is probably a bad idea.

Comment: @AMC It should return 0s. The code that Bhosale Shrikant shared works like a charm. Regarding the elements, it is not necessary that they should always be 3 in the list. Mine actually worked, but not for more than one 'NA' per list.

Comment: @Seifer Where is this data coming from? _Regarding the elements, it is not necessary that they should always be 3 in the list._ Are there any rules or patterns to it, then?

Comment: @AMC Myself. I am experimenting with different ways of solving things in base Python.
No patterns. Just that the 'NA' values should be replaced with the average sum of the other elements of the list and that all values should then be converted to floats

Comment: @Seifer Just to confirm, you create the input data? You want to practice parsing strings to floats?

Comment: @AMC Just part of problem. Yes, especially in a nested list

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205393/discussion-between-amc-and-seifer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data_var = [["1.2", "3.1", "0.2"], ["44.0", "NA", "90.0"]]


def replace_na_with_mean(list_entry):
    for i in range(len(list_entry)):
        index_list = []
        m = 0
        while 'NA' in list_entry[i]:
            index_list.append(list_entry[i].index('NA') + m)
            del list_entry[i][list_entry[i].index('NA')]
        if list_entry[i]:
            for n in range(len(list_entry[i])):
                list_entry[i][n] = float(list_entry[i][n])
        if index_list:
            if list_entry[i]:
                avg = sum(list_entry[i]) / len(list_entry[i])
            else:
                avg = 0
            for l in index_list:
                list_entry[i].insert(l, avg)
    return list_entry


print(replace_na_with_mean(data_var))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to use pandas functionality, since these types of operations are exactly what pandas was developed for. One can simply achieve what you want in just few lines of code:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [["1.2","NA","0.2"],["44.0","67.00","90.0"]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data).T.replace("NA", pd.np.nan).astype('<f8')
res = df.fillna(df.mean()).T.values.tolist()
```

which returns the wanted output:

```
[[1.2, 0.7, 0.2], [44.0, 67.0, 90.0]]
```

Btw your code works for me just fine in this simple case:

```
convert_data(data)
> [[44.0, 67.0, 90.0], [1.2, 0.7, 0.2]]
```

It will definitely start failing or giving faulty results in more complicated cases, f.e. if you have more than 1 `"NA"` value in the nested list, you will get ValueError exception (you will be trying to convert string into float).

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick, using `numpy`:

```py
import numpy as np

x=[["1.2","3.1","0.2"],["44.0","NA","90.0"]] 

#convert to float
x=np.char.replace(np.array(x), "NA", "nan").astype(np.float)

#replace nan-s with mean
mask=x.astype(str)=="nan"
x[mask]=np.nanmean(x, axis=1)[mask.any(axis=1)]
```

Output:

```py
[[ 1.2  3.1  0.2]
 [44.  67.  90. ]]
```

Answer (score 0):

One reason why your code ended up a little overcomplicated is that you tried to start by solving the problem of a "nested list." But really, all you need is a function that processes a list of numeric strings with some "NA" values, and then you can just apply that function to every item in the list.

```
def float_or_average(list_of_num_strings):
    # First, convert every item that you can to a number. You need to do this
    # before you can handle even ONE "NA" value, because the "NA" values need
    # to be replaced with the average of all the numbers in the collection.
    # So for now, convert ["1.2", "NA", "2.0"] to [1.2, "NA", 2.0]

    parsed = []

    # While we're at it, let's record the sum of the floats and their count,
    # so that we can compute that average.
    numeric_sum = 0.0
    numeric_count = 0

    for item in list_of_num_strings:
        if item == "NA":
            parsed.append(item)
        else:
            floating_point_value = float(item)
            parsed.append(floating_point_value)
            numeric_sum += floating_point_value
            numeric_count += 1
    # Now we can calculate the average:
    average = numeric_sum / numeric_count

    # And replace the "NA" values with them.
    for i, item in enumerate(parsed):
        if item == "NA":
            parsed[i] == average
    return parsed
    # Or, with a list comprehension (replacing the previous four lines of
    # code):
    return [number if number != "NA" else average for number in parsed]


# Using this function on a nested list is as easy as
example_data = [["1.2", "3.1", "0.2"], ["44.0", "NA", "90.0"]]
parsed_nested_list = []
for sublist in example_data:
    parsed_nested_list.append(float_or_average(sublist))
# Or, using a list comprehension (replacing the previous three lines of code):
parsed_nested_list = [float_or_average(sublist) for sublist in example_data]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def convert_data(data):

    for lst in data:

        sum = 0
        index_na = list()

        for elem in range(len(lst)):

            if lst[elem] != 'NA':
                sum += float(lst[elem])
                lst[elem] = float(lst[elem])
            else:
                index_na.append(elem)

        if len(index_na) > 0:
            len_values = sum / (len(lst)-len(index_na))

            for i in index_na:
                lst[i] = float("{0:.2f}".format(len_values))

    return data
```